# Is it legal for a company to enter an agreement not to hire employees from another company?

Tags: texas, labor-law

Is it legal for ACME Corp to enter a reciprocal agreement with another company to not hire from their workforce. This seems like it may have ramifications for price fixing the labor market.

Comment: You might need to be a bit more specific; this is against the law if Acme and Widgets Inc. are competitors, but a completely standard term if Widgets is a contractor of various varieties.

Comment: Is this a follow-up to [this Workplace question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/142013/illegal-business-tactics-when-dealing-with-contractors)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Among other stories via Google, some major companies lost a 2015 civil lawsuit brought by their employees: [Apple, Google, others settle antipoaching lawsuit for $415 million - CNET](https://www.cnet.com/news/apple-google-others-settle-anti-poaching-lawsuit-for-415-million/)

> Filed by former employees of the companies involved, the lawsuit shed
>   a light on the practice of some major tech industry players of
>   allegedly working together to agree not to poach employees from each
>   other. The affected employees had argued that such agreements limited
>   their ability to rise up in the industry and stifled their attempts to
>   earn higher salaries.

And the US DOJ prosecutes, too: [No More No-Poach: The Antitrust Division Continues to Investigate and Prosecute “No-Poach” and Wage-Fixing Agreements:](https://www.justice.gov/atr/division-operations/division-update-spring-2018/antitrust-division-continues-investigate-and-prosecute-no-poach-and-wage-fixing-agreements)

> The Antitrust Division protects labor markets and employees by
>   actively pursuing investigations into so-called “no-poach” and
>   wage-fixing agreements between employers. When companies agree not to
>   hire or recruit one another’s employees, they are agreeing not to
>   compete for those employees’ labor. The same rules apply when
>   employers compete for talent in labor markets as when they compete to
>   sell goods and services.

Comment: Just as a point of clarification, this would be different than an employment non-compete (or maybe non-disclosure) clause that would prevent you from leaving your current employer and going to work for a direct competitor for a reasonable period of time.  These non-compete clauses are not universally legal, and are highly dependent on local jurisdiction's laws on whether they would be enforceable or not.

Comment: @Milwrdfan The OP did not specify non-competes, so I did not address them. You should comment on the question itself or add your own answer.

Comment: This question is tagged with Texas. What does a settlement from California have to do with it? The DOJ's policy also only covers naked no-poach offers, which is vastly different than what your small snippet suggests. This answer is presently incomplete and dangerous to rely on.

Comment: @MichaelW.: The DoJ is a federal agency. It has jurisdiction in Texas.

Comment: @MichaelW. "This answer is presently incomplete and dangerous to rely on." 1) If you feel my answer is incomplete, write your own answer. 2) "Dangerous"? Read the sidebar; this site is not for legal advice and all takeaways are the risk of the reader; and and there is no attorney-client relationship here. If you really are a lawyer, as you claim to be, you'd know that.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch A disclaimer is not an excuse to give bad advice. I cannot write my own answer; the comment from chrylis requires an answer before an accurate answer can be given, and there is no sense in me asking it a second time. I merely upvoted his comment and moved on. I recommend others do the same.